# Que falla en este método?

Tags: c#, array, ordenamiento, ascii

Estoy tratando de ordenar las vocales sin utilizar ninguna función.
Para ello estoy tratando de pasar las vocales a código ASCII y tras esto compararlas con el resto de valores obtenidos, pero no consigo dar con la tecla exacta para hacerlo correctamente.
Hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo.

*Código*

```
const int VOCALES = 5;
        char[] vocalesAlfabet = new char[VOCALES] { 'O', 'I', 'U', 'E', 'A' };
        char[] vocalOrden = new char[VOCALES];
        //Array.Sort(vocalesAlfabet);
        //for (int i = 0; i < VOCALES; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(vocalesAlfabet[i]);
        //}
        int vocalOrdenPequeña;
        int[] vocalesAscii = new int[VOCALES];
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < vocalesAlfabet.Length; j++)
        {

            vocalesAscii[j] = Convert.ToInt32(vocalesAlfabet[j]);

            if (vocalesAscii[j] < (vocalesAscii[j]))
            {
                vocalOrdenPequeña = vocalesAscii[j];
                if (vocalOrdenPequeña < vocalesAscii[j])
                {


                    vocalesAlfabet[j] = Convert.ToChar(vocalesAscii[j]);

                }
                else
                {
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(vocalesAlfabet[j]);
        }
```

Tal y como está escrito ahora mismo, me devuelve las vocales en el mismo orden que ya están guardadas de serie.
Por qué no me ordena las vocales desde la A a la U?
Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Intenta ser más específico con el comportamiento que deseas. "Por qué no funciona como debería" no aporta una visión real del problema que planteas. Edita la pregunta añadiendo el resultado esperado y lo que te arroja en estos momentos.

Comment: Listo, creo que ya está formulada según los requísitos de la página.

Comment: No entiendo el planteamiento en sí, pero hay muchas cosas sin sentido:
   - if(vocalesAscii[j] < (vocalesAscii[j]+1)) SIEMPRE va a ser true
   - vocalOrdenPequeña = vocalesAscii[j]; 
      if(vocalOrdenPequeña < vocalesAscii[j])  SIEMPRE va a ser false, por lo que nunca modificarás el array

Comment: ya lo he editado tal cual como lo tengo ahora mismo.

Comment: Ahora tu primer if dice if (vocalesAscii[j] < (vocalesAscii[j])), o sea if a < a que es siempre false.

Answer (score 0):

Hay diferentes formas de ordenar

[Different ways to sort an array in descending order in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-sort-an-array-in-descending-order-in-c-sharp/)

Adapte el ultimo ejemplo a tu caso

```
public static void Main() 
{ 
    const int VOCALES = 5;
    char[] vocalesAlfabet = new char[VOCALES] { 'O', 'I', 'U', 'E', 'A' }; 

    int[] arr = new int[VOCALES]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < vocalesAlfabet.Length; j++)
    {
        arr[j] = Convert.ToInt32(vocalesAlfabet[j]);
    }


    int temp; 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) 

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++) 

            if (arr[i] < arr[j]) { 

                temp = arr[i]; 
                arr[i] = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = temp; 
            } 

    foreach(int value in arr) 
    { 
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(value) + " "); 
    } 
}
```

Pero basicamente convierto a un array de char a int y luego al contrario para mostrarlo

Comment: eso es precisamente lo que estoy intentando hacer yo, convertir los caracteres a ASCII y ordenar de menor a mayor

Comment: claro, por eso puse una alternativa para que evalues si la implementacion que propongo te ayuda a resolverlo